# URI is not valid and cannot be converted into a string when trying to load website

Tags: magento2, composer, elasticsearch, redis

#### Preconditions (*)

1. PHP 7.4.27
2. composer 2.1.4
3. Magento version 2.4.2-p2 enterprise
4. Elasticsearch 7.16.2
5. Redis Cache 5.0.14
6. Grunt 1.0.4

#### Steps to reproduce (*)

1. Install a fresh installation of Magento with multiple store views (3-4), and added my custom code for the website
2. Try to access the homepage

#### Expected result (*)

1. Site should load the default homepage

#### Actual result (*)

1. Site displays error saying URI is not valid and cannot be converted into a string
   [image]
   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be thrown if you for example have a redirected result set up, and the URL for it is not set correctly.

For example:

```
$redirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
$redirect->setUrl('a/b/c'); // this is missing = PROBLEM
return $redirect;
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the database, table `core_config_data`, and check the following:

1. do you have an entry with path `default` and value `NULL`? Delete that
2. does your `base_url` have any weird characters, for example a newline at the end?

Comment: Upon checking my base_url looks like that
web/unsecure/base_url => http://bb-com.barbour.uat/

Comment: No default path entry

Comment: Sorry, I meant "general", not "default"

Comment: No nothing like that again